# How to use multiple timer into recyclerView on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

In my application i want use multiple `CountDownerTimer` for show offer times into `RecyclerView`.
For write this application i used **Kotlin** language.
I write below codes, but when scrolling on `recyclerView`'s items start again this **timer**!

My mean is, timer started from **4:19**sec, when scrolling on items and after **10sec** show me **4:19** again instead of **4:09**!

Activity codes:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var apisList: ApisList
    private lateinit var retrofit: Retrofit
    private lateinit var todayAdapter: AuctionsTodayAdapter
    private val todayModel: MutableList<Today> = mutableListOf()
    private lateinit var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        //Initialize
        retrofit = ApiClient.instance
        apisList = retrofit.create(ApisList::class.java)
        todayAdapter = AuctionsTodayAdapter(themedContext, todayModel)
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(themedContext)
        //RecyclerView
        main_list.setHasFixedSize(true)
        main_list.layoutManager = layoutManager
        main_list.adapter = todayAdapter

        if (isNetworkAvailable()) getData(1, 10)
    }

    private fun getData(page: Int, limit: Int) {
        main_loader.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        val call = apisList.getAuctionsToday(page, limit)
        call.let {
            it.enqueue(object : Callback<AuctionsTodayResponse> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<AuctionsTodayResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                    main_loader.visibility = View.GONE
                    Log.e("auctionsTodayList", t.message)
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<AuctionsTodayResponse>, response: Response<AuctionsTodayResponse>) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        response.body()?.let { itBody ->
                            main_loader.visibility = View.GONE
                            if (itBody.toString().isNotEmpty()) {
                                todayModel.clear()
                                todayModel.addAll(itBody.res.today)
                                todayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter codes:

```
class AuctionsTodayAdapter(val context: Context, val model: MutableList<Today>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<AuctionsTodayAdapter.MyHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_main_list, parent, false)
        val holder = MyHolder(view)

        //holder.setIsRecyclable(false)

        return holder
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return model.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyHolder, position: Int) {
        val modelUse = model[position]
        holder.setData(modelUse)



        if (holder.newCountDownTimer != null) {
            holder.newCountDownTimer!!.cancel()
        }
        var timer = modelUse.calculateEnd

        timer = timer * 1000

        holder.newCountDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(timer, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                var seconds = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toInt()
                val hours = seconds / (60 * 60)
                val tempMint = seconds - hours * 60 * 60
                val minutes = tempMint / 60
                seconds = tempMint - minutes * 60
                holder.rowMain_timer.rowMain_timer.text =
                    String.format("%02d", hours) + ":" + String.format(
                        "%02d",
                        minutes
                    ) + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds)
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                holder.rowMain_timer.text = "00:00:00"
            }
        }.start()

    }

    inner class MyHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        var newCountDownTimer: CountDownTimer? = null

        lateinit var rowMain_timer: TextView

        init {
            rowMain_timer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowMain_timer)
        }

        fun setData(model: Today) {
            model.image.let {
                Glide.with(context)
                    .load(Constants.MAIN_BASE_URL + it)
                    .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE))
                    .into(itemView.rowMain_img)
            }
            model.title.let { itemView.rowMain_title.text = it }
        }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Because your code is written that way.

`onBindViewHolder(..)` is called whenever you scroll up/down and the view goes outside of visible area. Then that view is recycled and bound again to new list item (from model list). That's how it got the name `RecyclerView`.

To solve your problem, you need to put your countdown timer initialization codes inside model list item initialization (e.g. `Today` constructor).

Then the countdown timer will start and remain running within the Today object
and inside `onBindViewHolder(..)` just grab the remaining time value from that `Today` object.

Hope this helps!!

> **Update**
>   I am not experienced in kotlin. So you may need to modify it according
>   to kotlin. At some point you have `MutableList<Today>` preparation code
>   right?
>
> while creating a Today object, pass the adapter object as a constructor parameter.
>
> The following block should be inside your `Today` class.
>
> ```
> var newCountDownTimer : CountDownTimer
> var currentVal : String
>
> init {
>     newCountDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(timer, 1000) {
>         override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
>             var seconds = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toInt()
>             val hours = seconds / (60 * 60)
>             val tempMint = seconds - hours * 60 * 60
>             val minutes = tempMint / 60
>             seconds = tempMint - minutes * 60
>             currentVal =
>                     String.format("%02d", hours) + ":" + String.format(
>                         "%02d",
>                         minutes
>                     ) + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds)
>             // call adapter.notifyItemChanged(..) here
>         }
>
>         override fun onFinish() {
>             //here  you should call the adapter.notifyItemChanged(..) function with the position of this model in the model list
>         }
>     }.start()
> }
> ```
>
> your `onBindViewHolder` should look like this:
>
> ```
> override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyHolder, position: Int) {
>     val modelUse = model[position]
>     holder.setData(modelUse)
> }
> ```
>
> inside `Holder.setData(..)` function add this code
>
> ```
> rowMain_timer.text = model.currentVal
> ```
>
> Let me know if it helps.

Comment: can you send to me code with my codes? because i am amateur and really need your help. please

Comment: hey are you here my friend? can you help me?

Comment: what kind of help?

Comment: Can you send to me code with my above codes? please. because i am amateur and really need your help. please

Comment: I tried to explain with required code snippet based on your given codes. Check and let me know.

Comment: thanks dear, but you use this `newCountDownTimer` into `Today` model class? in Model class how can i use `holder.rowMain_timer.rowMain_timer.text = ...` ?!!!

Comment: Ahh!! I copied that block from your old code....corrected it. now check

Comment: thanks fro your help! i check it but not changed :D , and when use this countDownTimer into model class, how can i change my UI views in some times?! for example when receive to 10sec i want change textView color!

Comment: now updated. then instead of keeping currentVal inside Today class, you keep hours, minutes, seconds inside today class. and prepare the currentVal inside Holder setData(..) function. there you can check for your condition and have access to your UI view there.

Comment: thanks my friend, but you used adapter.notifyItemChanged(..) into model class. can you send to me code for this? because i am amateur and need your help. thanks . I'm sorry to take your time

Comment: pass the adapter object to the Today object as a constructor parameter like Today(..., adapter). You haven't posted those codes so I don't know how you are handling list preparation.

Comment: i used this code but not work me again :( do you have team viewer for connect to my system and see why not work? please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190371/discussion-between-abu-faisal-and-jake-warton).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried making use of 
1.`onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state)`
2.Restore state in the `onRestoreInstanceState()`
3. and `onResume()`.

this way you can keep track on your RecyclerList data.

Comment: can you send to me code with my codes? because i am amateur and really need your help. please

Comment: thanks, i really need your help. please help me tomorrow and don't forget this. please

Comment: are you here my friend? i wait you for help me